# Transferring my RotMG broswer account to steam

Tags: steam, pc, realm-of-the-mad-god

I have played realm of the mad god on the original browser for ages now and I want to play on steam. How do I transfer my browser account onto steam? Do I have a Kongregate account?

I have already downloaded steam and can play on the same email as my browser account but the game hasn't the same characters or vault.

Comment: Related: [ROTMG account linking](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/103704/13302)

Answer (score 3):

So after looking in game and doing some searches online it seems that *account linking is no longer possible nor supported* in the current version of the game. (since January 2015)

Here's an excerpt from a [Steam Community post](https://steamcommunity.com/app/200210/discussions/0/846964364015130496/) which explains the situation:

> ...As of January 2015, the "Replace" function is no longer working. This may be a side effect of a migration bug, which was never fixed. Please do not use this guide **if you're trying to replace your current Steam account with a browser account. *This is no longer possible.*** *(Emphasis mine)*

Note that the guide proposes a method of registering your Steam account *for continuing play in the browser **from** Steam.*